# extract all js scripts and style from HTML and add to textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I written code below that will extract the js like this:

```
src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"
src="assets/smooth-scroll/smooth-scroll.js"
```

I would like to have it like: (I guess my regex is wrong):

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/smooth-scroll/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
```

Here is my code:

```
$htmlData = file_get_contents($url);
if ($htmlData === false) {
echo "error!!";// Handle the error
die();
}
preg_match_all("/\<script(.*?)?\>(.|\\n)*?\<\/script\>/i", $htmlData, $matches);

//example output #1
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($matches[1]);
echo "</pre>";

//example output #2
$matches = $matches[1];
foreach ($matches as $val) {

//echo "<script";
echo $val;
//echo "</script>"; //<-- adding <script> tags breaks this code

}
```

So how would I add all scripts into a textarea from this point?
Not sure the regex for styles to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out my code:

```
$htmlData = file_get_contents($wurl);
if ($htmlData === false) {
echo "error!!";// Handle the error
die();
}

preg_match_all("/(\<script(.*?)?\>(?:.|\\n)*?\<\/script\>)/i", $htmlData, $scripts);
preg_match_all('/<link(.*?)?\>/is', $htmlData, $styles);
//$scripts.=implode(" ",$matches[2]);

//Print array for scripts to get array level;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($scripts[2]);
echo "</pre>";

//Print array for styles to get array level;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($styles[1]);
echo "</pre>";

$scripts = $scripts[2];
foreach ($scripts as $script) {
$all_scripts.= "%script ".$script."#%/scripts#"."\n";
} 

$styles = $styles[1];
foreach ($styles as $style) {
$all_styles.= "%link  ".$style."#"."\n";
} 

$all_scripts = str_replace(array('%', '#'), array(htmlentities('<'), htmlentities('>')), $all_scripts);                                               
$all_styles = str_replace(array('%', '#'), array(htmlentities('<'), htmlentities('>')), $all_styles);                                               

echo "<p>My Scripts:<br/>";                                            
echo $all_scripts;
echo "</p>";
echo "<p>My Styles:<br/>";                                             
echo $all_styles;
echo "</p>";
?>    

<textarea name="my_Styles" rows="8" cols="100">
<?php echo $all_styles; ?>
</textarea>

<textarea name="my_Scripts"rows="8" cols="100">
<?php echo $all_scripts; ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the script part in the captured segment.

```
preg_match_all("/(\<script(.*?)?\>(?:.|\\n)*?\<\/script\>)/i", $htmlData, $matches);
```

Comment: Code is still giving me the same results.